# How is training for an SIC type rating accomplished when an aircraft is two pilot certified only?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

For an aircraft which is certified for two pilots and a simulator doesn’t exist, how does someone go about receiving the required training for an SIC type rating without having the type rating already, since two type certificates pilots are required for the operation of the aircraft? Furthermore, how can the pilot in SIC training log anything to meet the experience requirements for the SIC type rating when you cannot log anything for a type in which you are not rated (category, class, and type), much less act as a required crew member? This question is specifically in regard to FAA regulations.

Comment: Last I heard, an SIC type is the result of some sort of international standardization.  There is no requirement to be "typed" as an SIC to serve as an SIC while flying a US registered aircraft within the NAS.  As such, no training is required to occupy the SIC position other than to be category and class rated.  So, you and the PIC can legally fly the plane while you receive your SIC type training.  Now insurance coverage is another story.